# c++ program crashes before main

Tags: c++

When I run my code below, the program crashes and the compiler message is Segmentation fault. I've searched for bugs in my code but I can't find any. My program doesn't even seem to enter main(), because I've tried using 'cout' to see where it crashes but I get no output, even when 'cout'-ing immedeately after main starts. Here is the code. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct edge_t
{

    int a,b,w;
};
bool comp(edge_t a, edge_t b)
{
    if(a.w < b.w)
        return true;
    return false;
}

vector<int> parent;

int find_parent(int x)
{
    if(parent[x] == x)
        return x;
    parent[x] = find_parent(parent[x]);
    return parent[x];
}
void join(int a,int b)
{
    parent[find_parent(a)] = find_parent(b);
    return;
}

int mst(vector<edge_t> v)
{

    sort(v.begin() , v.end() , comp);
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)
        parent[i] = i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)
    {
        if(find_parent(v[i].a) != find_parent(v[i].b))
        {
            join(v[i].a, v[i].b);
            sum += v[i].w;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    cout<<"Hello?\n"; ///does not display anything QQ
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    parent.resize(n);
    int p,q,r;
    vector<edge_t> edges;
    int s =0;
    for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %d",&p,&q,&r);
        edge_t tmp;
        tmp.a = p;
        tmp.b = q;
        tmp.w = r;
        s+=r;
        edges.push_back(tmp);
    }
    printf("%d\n", s - mst(edges));



    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the online ide on hackerrank.com (I'm practising problems there).

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: How are you compiling this? This compiles and runs successfully for me with `g++ test.cpp test` and with an input of `test` on OS X

Comment: Use `std::endl` instead of `"\n"`, as that guarantees the stream is flushed. And step through the code in a debugger - typically, when it crashes, the debugger will show you where in the code the crash is.

Comment: Also avoid mixing `printf` and `cout` - not because it won't work, but sometimes it can be confusing.

Comment: So from here: http://ideone.com/GQJhoN it looks like your code is at least getting to the for loop. I would suggest a debugger.

Comment: You need to flush the stream for your output to be visible. This is difference between C and C++ in outputting a string with a newline at the end.

Comment: I don't see the point of `find_parent`. If `parent[x] != x` it calls itself recursively with the exact same argument, and with the same contents as before in `parent` (the assignment to `parent[x]` can't happen until `find_parent(x)` has been evaluated). Also, why would a `find` function modify a global variable?

Comment: @AndyG, wrong. It will be initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `mst` function

```
for (int i = 0; i<v.size(); ++i)
    parent[i] = i;
```

This assumes that `parent` has the same or more elements that `v`, and if that's not the case, your program crashes.

In the same function, you are calling `find_parent` and you haven't verified that `a` & `b` are lower than `parent.size()`, which would be fine if you checked that in your `find_parent` function, but you don't check it there either.

```
if (find_parent(v[i].a) != find_parent(v[i].b))
{
    join(v[i].a, v[i].b);
    sum += v[i].w;
}
```

Therefore, if `find_parent` gets invalid input, your program crashes

```
int find_parent(int x)
{
    if (parent[x] == x)
        return x;
}
```

Comment: There is no invalid input, the program is for practising on hackerrank.com .

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem it was the for loop that initializes the parent array. It didn't catch my attention as the program didn't even seem to enter main to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your compilation environment if you have an instruction set enabled that your system does not support (e.g. AVX) crashes can occur prior to main (I have seen this happen on Windows with VC++). Try compiling with all optimisations switched off, for an "ancient" target architecture.

Depending on your platform, this could also be due to shared libraries not being found, although this seems less likely.

EDIT: Deleted the bit about cout since you have a end line character and main. That was an off thought.

Comment: `main` doesn't need to take any arguments in C++. See variant 1 at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: Why do want OP's main to be like this?

Comment: `endl` flushes the stream. Furthermore, AVX and/or optimisations doesn’t really explain the crash, unless you also explain any undefined behaviour in the code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph An unsupported instruction set certainly can explain this. I have seen _precisely_ that problem on Windows with VC++. You're right about endl. I didn't see it in the OPs post.

Comment: @Michael You're right. Since it apparently crashes before main in the OPs environment it seemed worth trying.

Comment: @JarraMcIntyre Yes, good point about the instruction set actually.